# Python: Change the format of python object date-time to string and change it back to python object to be comparable with other date?

Tags: python, datetime, formatting

I have a code in which I have two dates inputs (in different formats) and I want them to be the same format (date-time python object) and so I will be able to compare these two days. One of them is a string and the other is a python object:

```
import pythonwhois
import datetime
from datetime import date
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime

bl_time = l.split('\t')
bl_time = bl_time.strip('\n')
bl_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(bl_time ,"%b %d %Y").strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
date1 = datetime.strptime(bl_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
w = pythonwhois.get_whois(domain)
date2 = (w['creation_date'])[0].strftime(bl_date, '%d/%m/%Y').strptime(bl_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

and i am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/scripts/whois.py", line 29, in <module>
    bl = datetime.datetime.strptime(bl_time ,"%b %d %Y").strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did `from datetime import datetime`, in your code, `datetime` is the **class**, not the **module**.  Change

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(bl_time, ...).strftime(...)`
```

to

```
datetime.strptime(bl_time, ...).strftime(...)`
```

and you should be all set<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>at least as far as this error is concerned... ;-)</sup>

Comment: @mglison Thanks man! This works. What about date 2? Cause that does not work either

Comment: @Mee -- I have no idea.  I'm not familiar with the `pythonwhois` package, so I can't really give much help on that one.  you could ask a new question about it -- But I'd spend a little time trying to understand the traceback first...